# Play youtube without opening tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

If I open this href contained in fiddle in a new tab : https://jsfiddle.net/fNPvf/30636/ (press ctrl + click link) the link is opened in a new tab and focus stays on current tab but the youtube video does not play unless focus is given to the tab, ie the tab is clicked. How to play the youtube video when open in new tab regardless if focus is given to opened tab ?

fiddle src :

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/rTFUM4Uh_6Y?rel=0&autoplay=1" target="_blank">Nessum dorma</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working as intended.

Previously browsers were allowed to open and play videos and flash unattended on another tab.

This led to abuses eg. where people would increase their youtube revenue by playing videos unattended continuously.

It also increased computer cpu and memory load.  To reduce this, the browser developers have made it a lot harder for any script or video to play in another tab - not impossible, but heavily restricted to only that which is necessary for the page to load.